# i see grey code in android studio. What is grey code mean?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley

I'm try to learning how can ı use api for android studio. I found document on google but it's not working or i making something wrong.
I copied that code from "https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request". But when i pasted code and imported "com.android.volley.Response;" , i see grey lines on my code like a comment line.

[grey codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3lbu.png).

What is grey code mean? What should i do?

Comment: Grey code is not an error. It's a listener to get a response from API to check whether your API data is successfully grabbed or not. If not then it will go into onErrorResponse() method and print the error message.

Comment: what is your problem? please put your Logcat or any error message and relevant code.

Comment: I understand what is a problem. I can't access API. Because my api starting with http. Android studio expect a https. How can i access http api. Is it possible? Or i must change my api?  Api is="http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=********************"

Comment: Add below line in your manifest.xml file in <application> tag :::::::: ===> 
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Also, add below line outside <application> tag in your manifest.xml:====>
<uses-configuration android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

Answer (score 2):

Grey codes usually mean that those code lines are redundant. You could have replaced them with lambda.

For example without writing,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
    }
});
```

you can write,

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    ...
});
```